# CSS boxes positioning

Tags: css, positioning

```
.box {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
    background-color: #d1d1d1;
    width: 100px; height: 30px;
}

.box.l { height: 70px; }
```

[There are fixed-sizes boxes](http://jsfiddle.net/RayZ/nEMxZ/) floating left. Small one are half-height of middle one.

```
<div class="box s"></div>
<div class="box s"></div>
<div class="box l"></div>
<div class="box s"></div>
<div class="box s"></div>
```

How can i get small one are arranged on each other without using any containers (2 small on each other, then big one on the right side and 2 small on each other again)? Is it possible to make an optimal fit bor those boxes?

Any suggestions?

Comment: What does small of each other mean?

Comment: Sorry for my poor english. One above other. One small box on other other one.

Comment: Oh okay, no problem, sry, just didn't understand

Comment: I am tryin to find "clean" solution, without containers, tables, etc..

Comment: That having been said, you 'can' do this with divs, of course, but I'd hate to help you only to find out it wasn't as cross-browser friendly as using something like the table, tr, and td elements.

Comment: Honestly, I think 'tables' will be cleaner here.

Comment: I am checking out your fiddle now, I will get back to you soon

Comment: It's a tough one. I'm not sure exactly how it's supposed to look; something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/nEMxZ/14/

Comment: isherwood has the right idea, you're gonna need more classes and such than you have. An alternative answer, again, would be to use tables, but I won't post that answer, if you're sure that's not what you're looking for.

Comment: Maybe this might help? http://masonry.desandro.com/ not sure if you literally just want to style these boxes or if this is a more wide ranging thing. If it's the former then I'd suggest more classes or using containers

Answer (score 4):

I hate myself for doing this, but somehow it works ..

```
.box {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
    background-color: #d1d1d1;
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.box.l { height: 70px; float: left; position: relative; left: 110px; top: -80px; }
.box.l + .box.s,
.box.l + .box.s + .box.s { position: relative; top: -80px; left: 110px; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nEMxZ/13/

(you should really use containers)

Comment: Not bad. Similar to my second answer, but probably more old-browser-compliant.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm just gonna post how to do this using the table element, and I'll let you decide which is cleaner.

```
.box {
    margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
    background-color: #d1d1d1;
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
}

.boxes {
    border-spacing: 10px;
}

<table class="boxes">
    <tr>
        <td class="box"></td>
        <td class="box" rowspan="2"></td>
        <td class="box"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="box"></td>
        <td class="box"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here's the jsfiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/nEMxZ/22/

I think I've got this about as clean as you can get it, should you decide to use a table here. Notice I've alleviated the need for two different classes for the boxes themselves, but added one for the table.

Comment: Have in mind that `cellspacing` is not a valid attribute in HTML 5 anymore, so use `table { border-spacing:10px; }`

Comment: @Floremin Thank you for that, to be honest I was afraid of that. I will edit my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Normally this would require nesting your elements in a grid:

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/nEMxZ/11/

```
.wrapper {
    float: left;
}
.box {
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
    background-color: #d1d1d1;
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
}
.box.l {
    height: 70px;
}


<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="box s"></div>
    <div class="box s"></div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="box l"></div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="box s"></div>
    <div class="box s"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, this is obvoius. But the key of my question - it there solve without any wrappers?

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach, though it's rather fragile and won't support older browsers:

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/nEMxZ/19/

```
.box {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
    background-color: #d1d1d1;
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
}
.box.l {
    height: 70px;
    margin-top: -40px;
}
.box.s:nth-child(2) {
    clear: left;
}
.box.s:nth-child(4) {
    margin-top: -40px;
}

<div class="box s">One</div>
<div class="box s">Two</div>
<div class="box l">Three</div>
<div class="box s">Four</div>
<div class="box s">Five</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Like this?

```
.box.l {
    float: right;
    clear: both;
}

.box.s { 
    clear: both;
}
```

[Your jsFiddle edited](http://jsfiddle.net/nEMxZ/10/)

Comment: No offense, Cedric, but did you look at this in jsfiddle before you posted it?